# How to detect clicks on stacked elements?

Tags: javascript

I created a demo with 3 DIVs which a bit stacked / overlapping. If I click on a point with more than one div only the alert for "highest" DIV pops up. How can I detect the click for all DIVs at the point?

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("testBox")[0].onclick = () => { 
 alert("test 1");
}

document.getElementsByClassName("testBox")[1].onclick = () => { 
 alert("test 2");
}

document.getElementsByClassName("testBox")[2].onclick = () => { 
 alert("test 3");
}
```

```css
.testBox {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 30px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.testBox:nth-child(2) {
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
  left: 30px;
}

.testBox:nth-child(3) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="testBox"></div>
<div class="testBox"></div>
<div class="testBox"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could listen to the document's click event and check if the mouse position falls inside each div's `getBoundingClientRect`

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

To get the click position, do `event.clientX` or `.clientY`

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent

Comment: Thanks for the tipp. I hoped for an easier solution but I will trie it

Answer (score -1):

Create a parent `div` enclosing all `div`s.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName("testBox")[0].onclick = () => { 
 alert("test 1");
}

document.getElementsByClassName("testBox")[1].onclick = () => { 
 alert("test 2");
}

document.getElementsByClassName("testBox")[2].onclick = () => { 
 alert("test 3");
}
document.getElementsByClassName("par")[0].onclick = () => { 
 alert("par");
}
```

```css
.testBox {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background: lightblue;
  margin: 30px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.testBox:nth-child(2) {
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
  left: 30px;
}

.testBox:nth-child(3) {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="par">
<div class="testBox"></div>
<div class="testBox"></div>
<div class="testBox"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If I click in the center (covered by all 3 blue divs) only the third alert pops up and the parent (by event bubble). Tested with FF and Chrome.